# How can ad interstitial ads from Non Activity Class?

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

I have a non activity class named CustomBinding which shows images on main activity which loads images from the asset folder and sets wallpapers on click I want to show interstitial ad from Non Activity class

```
package com.annasblackhat.materiallivewallpaper.util;

import android.databinding.BindingAdapter;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

/**
 * Created by Git Solution on 19/08/2017.
 */

public class CustomBinding {
    @BindingAdapter("imgAsset")
    public static void setImageAsset(ImageView imageView, String asset){
        Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
                .load(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/"+asset))
                .into(imageView);
    }

    @BindingAdapter("imgDrawable")
    public static void setImageDrawable(ImageView imageView, String drawable){
        int img = Integer.parseInt(drawable);

        Glide.with(imageView.getContext())
                .load(img)
                .into(imageView);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the ads using context of you activity, grab the context class form you desire non-activity class.

```
private void showAd(Context context){

    MobileAds.initialize(context,
        "AD_ID");

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("AD_UNIT_ID");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
       @Override
       public void onAdLoaded() {
          if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
              mInterstitialAd.show();
          }
       }

       @Override
       public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
           // Code to be executed when an ad request fails.
       }

       @Override
       public void onAdOpened() {
           // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.
       }

       @Override
       public void onAdLeftApplication() {
           // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
       }

       @Override
       public void onAdClosed() {
           // Code to be executed when when the interstitial ad is closed.
       }
    });


}
```

And call that method by this `showAd(imageView.getContext())`

But better you make a [Singleton class](https://gist.github.com/money4honey/30a75cb93608211c87aa) for loading and showing interstitial with application context.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a singleton class like that

```
public class AdClass {
public static AdClass instance;
InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

public static AdClass getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new AdClass();
        return instance;
    }
    return instance;
}

public void AdShow(Context context) {
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-40063938313***14/61589******");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID").build());
    Log.d("TAG", "GOO");
    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
            Log.d("TAG=", "GOO");
        }
    });
}
```

}

And call from another class or Activity with context

```
AdClass.getInstance().AdShow(context);
```

Or if you need to Application Context then please add this class

```
    public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static MyApplication instance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
    public static MyApplication getInstance() {
        if(instance==null)
        {
            instance=new MyApplication();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

And don't forget to add MyApplication class in manifest

```
<application
     .........................
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    ........................
   </application>
```

Now replace context with

```
AdClass.getInstance().AdShow(MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: please solution for this error "cannot resolve symbol context"

Comment: If you call from Activity then AdClass.getInstance().AdShow(YOURACTIVITY.this); // example : AdClass.getInstance().AdShow(MainActivity.this);

Comment: you need to create MyApplication class. please see uper solution

Comment: i create MyApplication class https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=500725374480

Comment: manifest screenshot https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo?album_id=5307010426&photo_id=500725375245

Comment: im sorry I can't access this screenshot.

Comment: https://scontent-mrs1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/30706791_2083245625264276_8514181071229681664_n.png?_nc_cat=0&oh=336f5ca391aab49876a4c90548e25120&oe=5B27AFB0

Comment: https://scontent-mrs1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/30738108_2083244935264345_3528385491307069440_n.png?_nc_cat=0&oh=80dee08c0afc197481df0ac5e02209b1&oe=5B673796

Comment: android:name=".MyApplication" change to android:name=".activity.MyApplication"

Comment: @MortuzaShahariar that is a pretty bad implementation in terms of design pattern (i) Application class is already singleton no need to make its context static to achieve singleton. (ii) Static context of the application within an AdMob thread will cause the memory leak/ANR in several scenarios.

Comment: I appreciate.Thanks.